# Flatten returing only the first item in chararray

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have the following data (loaded in variable A):

```
(a1:a2:a3|a4:a5:a6)
(b1:b2:b3)
(c1:c2:c3|c4:c5:c6|c7:c8:c9)
```

I want my final output to be as follows:

```
(a1:a2:a3)
(a4:a5:a6)
(b1:b2:b3)
(c1:c2:c3)
(c4:c5:c6)
(c7:c8:c9)
```

Here is what I did:

```
B = foreach B generate flatten(STRSPLIT($0, '\\|')) as splitted:chararray;
```

This converted the data to:

```
(a1:a2:a3,a4:a5:a6)
(b1:b2:b3)
(c1:c2:c3,c4:c5:c6,c7:c8:c9)
```

with the following structure:

```
B: {splitted: chararray}
```

However, when I try to flatten this chararray into separate tuples it only spits out the first item. I have tried several different ways to get the output I want but I always get the first item. Here are a couple of things I tried:

```
req_output = foreach B generate flatten(STRSPLIT(splitted, ','));

req_output = foreach B generate flatten(TOBAG(*));
```

In both cases I get the following output:

```
(a1:a2:a3)
(b1:b2:b3)
(c1:c2:c3)
```

I am not sure why this is happening. How can I get all the items as different tuples? I do not have much experience in pig so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `relation B` you are storing only the first item(i.e `splitted variable`), that is the reason for this issue. Can you remove the variable `splitted` from the relation B?

```
B = foreach B generate flatten(STRSPLIT($0, '\\|')) as splitted:chararray;
```

**TO**

```
B = foreach B generate flatten(STRSPLIT($0, '\\|'));
```

You can solve this problem in couple of ways.

**input:**

```
a1:a2:a3|a4:a5:a6
b1:b2:b3
c1:c2:c3|c4:c5:c6|c7:c8:c9
```

**Option1: Using TOKENIZE**

```
A = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage() AS(line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(line,'\\|'));
DUMP B;
```

**Option2: Using STRSPLIT + TOBAG**

```
A = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage() AS(line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(line,'\\|'));
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(TOBAG(*));
DUMP C;
```

**Option3: Using STRSPLITTOBAG (Only in Pig Version 0.14)**

```
A = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage() AS(line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLITTOBAG(line,'\\|'));
DUMP B;
```

**Output:**

```
(a1:a2:a3)
(a4:a5:a6)
(b1:b2:b3)
(c1:c2:c3)
(c4:c5:c6)
(c7:c8:c9)
```